# How do you call a reference array in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, syntax, reference

So, my knowledge is lacking on both references and recursives.

Consider the following:

```
int sumelements(int arraylength, int &list){
  return list[arraylength] + sumelements(arraylength - 1, *list);
}
int main(){
  int arraylength = 10;
  int list[arraylength] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  sumelements(arraylength-1, *list);
}
```

Line 2 causes an error, assumingly because my syntax is wrong, though like I said I am new to both concepts.

Also, I know it's a loop, I'd just like it to compile.

Comment: You use `list` like it was an array or pointer. You cannot use it this way. Simplifying - use a reference the same way you use normal variable, but have in mind, that reference **references** to some other variable.

Comment: I have added two lines in main and one in sum elements to clarify the issue

Comment: `int sumelements(int arraylength, int* list){...}` and `sumelements(arraylength-1, list);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sumelements` is accessing a particular element of `list`, so you need to change your `list` parameter from `int&` to `int*` (or `list[]`, which is identical to `int*` when used in a function parameter) so that `operator[]` will work correctly.  Then change both `main` and `sumelements` to pass `list` without using `operator*` at all.  When you refer to a fixed-length array by just its name, it decays into a pointer to the 1st element, so `main` can pass the array as just `list` by itself.

Also, you have endless recursion, as you don't have a stop condition in `sumelements`, so it will just keep calling itself endlessly, causing **undefined behavior** once `arraylength` becomes `< 0`.

Also, in `main`, you are declaring your `list` array using an `arraylength` value that is not known at compile-time, only at runtime.  Declaring a fixed-length array in this manner is not allowed by the C++ standard, but some compilers (notably gcc) support it as a compiler extension.  Do not rely on this behavior, as it is not portable.  Declare `arrayLength` as `const` so it will be known at compile-time.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int sumelements(int index, int *list)
{
  if (index < 0) return 0;
  return list[index] + sumelements(index - 1, list);
}

int main()
{
  const int arraylength = 10;
  int list[arraylength] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::cout << sumelements(arraylength - 1, list);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/y1Jgvm)

That being said, a more C++-ish way to handle this would be to use the standard [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) algorithm instead of a recursive function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
  const int arraylength = 10;
  int list[arraylength] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  std::cout << std::accumulate(list, list+arraylength, 0);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Ep3KJd)

Comment: Its worth to notice, that you've added `const` in `arraylength`. Creating automatic arrays with not compile-time known size is forbidden in C++. It works only in GCC as an extension.

Comment: I would even say: `std::accumulate(std::begin(list), std::end(list), 0)` to get rid of `arraylength`.

Comment: So, is the first code example not passing the array by pointer instead of reference?

Comment: @trisimix: yes, my first example is passing the array by pointer. Your original code doesn't pass the array by pointer OR reference, it passes *a single `int`* by reference instead, which is why `list[arraylength]` and `*list` cause errors.

Comment: @Jarod42: `std:begin()` and `std::end()` were added in C++11, which not everyone uses, so I didn't mention them. But, to really get rid of `arrayLength` completely, you would have to also declare `list` as `int list[] = {...};` so the compiler can deduce the array size

Comment: Is your answer any functionally different than:
int sumelements(int arraylength, int list[]){

sumelements(arraylength, list);

Comment: @trisimix: in a function parameter, `int *list` and `int list[]` are treated identical (ie, as an `int*` pointer)

Comment: I read somewhere that c++ passes arrays by pointer by default?
edit: ohhhhh thank you.

Comment: @trisimix: If you pass the array by just its name, yes.  I mentioned this in my answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau: We are in 2018, if user is limited to old version, I assume that he has to mention it. (I don't assume than everyone has newest version, but C++14 seems reasonable IMO (~4 years)).

Comment: @Jarod42: I see a lot of people who are still not even using C++11 yet (including me!). So I don't like to make assumptions about which versions are being used if not stated.  I like to provide answers that apply to multiple versions, with version-oriented answers only if a version is actually stated.

Comment: Some people cannot use exception, std::vector, stl, ... so they should state it. You mention `std::accumulate` which might be forbidden if OP is a student ;-) I stop here the digression..

Answer (score 0):

This is just playing around, possibly helping to understand references, however, ***not*** intended to actually be used in real code!!!

It *can* be done with references, too, if one does it right:

```
int sumelements(int arraylength, int& list)
{
    if(arraylength < 0) // stolen from Remy...
        return 0;

    return (&list)[arraylength] + sumelements(arraylength - 1, list);
    //     ^^^^^^^ 
}
```

Well, as `list` still references the first integer in your array, by taking the address of it you get back the pointer you need - which you then can use with an offset (index). In the recursive call, you pass on `list` just as is, and same again.

As mentioned already: This is just for understanding, don't do it this way, use pointers as Remy did!

Comment: Ahhh thanks for clarifying. I was sitting in a lab and wondering how to do this and my TA couldn't figure out how, I get why not to do it now.

Comment: "*my TA couldn't figure out how*" - then your teacher needs to find a better TA who knows what they are doing.

Comment: Yeah but then I'd have to pay more for school